# With winforms, how to execute Action2 originated by Action1 outside of stack of Action1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have `Action2` which is working great whenever called autonomously, e.g. from menu item, but this action shows strange bugs when called from `Action1`.

How can I initiate launch of `Action2` from `Action1` in the way that `Action1` will not be in stack of `Action2`?

My current solution is using a `Timer` control.

Is there a more elegant solution?

```
Timer handoverToAction2 = new Timer();

void Action1()
{
 DoWhateverNeeded();
 handoverToAction2.Start();
}

void handoverToAction2_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 handoverToAction2.Stop();
 Action2();
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `Action1` will *always* be in the stack of `Action2` in *some way*, that's how the stack works, or am I missing something here?

Comment: There's nowhere near enough code to see what's going on here.  You haven't given any indication what `Action1` and `Action2` even are.

Comment: @miroxlav For example making **bold** your variables, when you should've formatted as `code`.

Comment: @Servy - `Action1` is event coming from another keyboard, barcode scanner or RFID reader. `Action2` is logout closing all MDI forms and displaying Login form. But whenever I perform logout from such event (=`Action1` on stack), form events in Login form are *gone* EXCEPT of first time. They all get processed once Login form is closed (EXCEPT of first time). Code is pretty trivial on my side, it looks like some WinForms bug (or strange feature).

Comment: Sounds like you're simply trying to do UI work in a non-UI thread.  Don't do that; you need to marshal to the UI thread to do UI work.

Comment: @Servy - I'm marshalling everything to main thread using `Send()` before doing any UI stuff. But I still have the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to start action2 on a different thread. A guaranteed way to do so it to create a Thread instance, and call the action using the ThreadStartDelegate. However, if that's not critical, and you're more interested in doing those in parallel I'd suggest using TPL.
So you'll just need to do this:
Task action2Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action2);

Hope this helps !

---

*Additional answer after clarification:*

So it seems you should spring the `Action2` from `Action1` through the **Dispatcher**:
`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action2);`

Comment: I was thinking about this but `Action2` does UI stuff, too. I shouldn't work with UI on 2 threads.

Comment: Use dispatcher then:
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action2)

Comment: Could you please make your last comment part of the answer? It covers my case. Then the answer will become 'acceptable' :) The current answer can be put below the `-----` line, because it is slightly off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to invoke over to the main thread to have `Action2` run there. Here's an example from a WinForm where `Action1` invokes over to main thread to call `Action2`. When I check the stack trace in the debugger here, it looks like `Action2` is not in the call stack of `Action1`.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Action action2 = () => Console.WriteLine("Action 2");
        Action action1 = () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Action1");
                BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    action2();
                });
            };

        action1();
    }
```